# Zend PDF wysiwyg editor output

Tags: php, zend-framework, wysiwyg, zend-pdf

I'm currently building a PDF editor. I have a problemen with implementing the processing of the tags.

I want to allow the following tags:
[h1],[h2],[h3],[h4],[h4],[h5],[h6],[strong]

I've build an class with a method called drawText(code below).

The [h1] tag will change the font size and the font weight. As you can see in the code I'm outputting lines of text. 
Example text line:
This is your [strong]boarding pass[/strong], please save this PDF file on your smartphone or tablet and [strong]show it at the gate[/strong].

I'd like to make the text between the [strong] bold. To do this with Zend_PDF I need to set the TTF file with the bold text and then find the current X-coordinate and call $this->pdf()->drawText(text, X-coordinate, Y-coordinate, charset). I've been thinking and trying for hours to write the code which makes this possible(tried using explode, preg_match_all, etc), but I can't get it to work...

I believe I'm not the only one with this problem, and I hope someone has thought about this and can help a little by telling how he or she did it...

Hope to hear from someone and thanks in advance!

```
/**
 * drawSplittedText()
 * 
 * @param array $text
 * @return object Application_Plugin_PdfPlugin
 */
public function drawSplittedText(Array $text)
{
    // Count the number of rows.
    $textRowCount = count($text);

    $i = 0;        

    foreach ($text as $row)
    {           
        // Replace tabs, because they're not outputted properly.
        $row = str_replace("\t", '    ', $row);

        // If the character encoding of the currrent row not is UTF-8, convert the row characters to UTF-8.
        if (($rowEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($row)) != 'UTF-8') {
            $row = iconv($rowEncoding, 'UTF-8', $row);
        }

        // Output row on PDF
        $this->pdf()->drawText($row, $this->_defaultMarginleft, $this->currentY, 'UTF-8');

        $this->newLine();

        ++$i;               
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is probably where most people start when rendering text with `Zend_Pdf`, but unfortunately you are going to have to develop something a litte more complex to achieve your goals.

Firstly, you are going to need to keep track of the current x and y location, along with the current font type and size.

Then you'll need a helper function/method to calculate how much space a chunk of text is going to need when rendered in the current font and size.

I would then suggest breaking up your rendering code as follows:

```
function writeParagraph( $text )
{
    // Looks for the next tag and sends all text before that tag to the
    // writeText() function. When it gets to a tag it changes the current
    // font/size accordingly, then continues sending text until it runs out
    // of text or reaches another tag. If you need to deal with nested tags
    // then this function may have to call itself recursively.
}

function writeText( $text )
{
    // The first thing this function needs to do is call getStringWidth() to
    // determine the width of the text that it is being asked to render and if
    // the line is too long, shorten it. In practice, a better approach is to
    // split the words into an array based on the space between each word and
    // then use a while() loop to start building the string to be rendered
    // (start with first word, then add second word, then add third word, etc),
    // in each iteration testing the length of the current string concatenated
    // with the next word to see if the resulting string will still fit. If you
    // end up with a situation where adding the next word to the current string
    // will result in a string that is too long, render the current string and
    // a line feed then start the process again, using the next word as the first
    // word in the new string. You will probably want to write a bonus line feed
    // at the end as well (unless, of course, you just wrote one!).
}

function getStringWidth( $str )
{
    // This needs to return the width of $str
}
```

I have a sample class (https://github.com/jamesggordon/Wrap_Pdf) that implements the `writeText()` and `getStringWidth()` functions/methods, plus includes all of the other stuff, like current location, current style, etc. If you can't figure out the code for the `writeParagraph()` function let me know and I'll include it in `Wrap_Pdf`.